# Convert custom dimension in Universal Analytics to GA4

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

TLDR: What would be the equivalent setup in GA4 for this UA dimension?

```
UA
[Custom Dimension name]   [Index]   [Scope]   [Last Changed]    [State]
myDimension               1         Hit       Jul 4, 2018       Active

GA4
[Dimension name]  [Description] [Scope]   [User Property/Parameter] [Last changed]
myDimension                      ??        ??                        Mar 30, 2022
```

Long explanation
Because Universal Analytics(UA) is deprecated we need to switch to GA4. We would like the new setup to resemble the old UA setup a much as possible. We have a custom dimension setup in UA with the scope Hit. GA4 does not have a scope Hit. It seems logical that the UA scope Hit is somewhat equal to the GA4 scope Event. Is this true, and if not what are the differences?

Furthermore in GA4 there is also an Event Parameter. The documentation ( https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en&utm_id=ad#scope&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) does not really explain what this property does. Since UA does not have this property, what would be the value in GA4 that is most equal to the way UA tracked data.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:** An Event Parameter.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11396839?hl=en

In Universal Analytics, some "Hits" were an event, some "Hits" were for example a "pageView".
In GA4, *everything* is an event. That's why the equivalent to the "Hit" Scope is now "event" Scope.